# Computational complexity of random sampling

Tags: cc.complexity-theory, counting-complexity, randomness, pr.probability

I am using some randomized algorithms (particle filters) and I would like to know what is the computational complexity of obtaining one random sample of a continuous distribution (for instance from a multivariate Gaussian), in terms of elemental operations... or what computational complexities have conventional algorithms.

Thank you

Comment: It depends on your computational model. Sometimes people just assume you can generate a Gaussian as a unit operation. However, if all you can generate is, say, random bits, and you want an approximate Gaussian, the complexity depends on the approximation you want.

Comment: @DanaMoshkovitz: maybe this could be an answer ?

Comment: Ok, I posted it as an answer.

Comment: FYI In the case of a finite distribution (not what op asks!), $O(1)$ time is (in theory) possible.  See https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/37648/random-sampling-data-structure-with-removal.

Answer (score 8):

The answer depends on your computational model. Sometimes people just assume you can generate a Gaussian as a unit operation. However, if all you can generate is, say, random bits, and you want an approximate Gaussian, the complexity depends on the approximation you want.

Comment: A more precise question would be, if you want to sample a distribution from random iid bits that is $\epsilon$-close to a Gaussian in total variational distance, what is the running time dependence of the sampler in $\epsilon$.

Answer (score 5):

A related pointer (though not a complete answer) is [the book by Luc Devroye](http://cg.scs.carleton.ca/~luc/rnbookindex.html) on generating random draws from different kinds of distributions. While the book doesn't have detailed complexity analysis, it outlines a number of very specific algorithms for sampling from different densities, and provides good pointers to do a proper running time analysis.

Comment: The link is broken, I guess the new one is: http://www.nrbook.com/devroye/

Answer (score 2):

Donald Knuth's [The Art of Computer Programming](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Art_of_Computer_Programming#Chapters) has algorithms for generating many common distributions in volume two, chapter three.