# Examples of Gaussian randomized algorithms

Tags: ds.algorithms, reference-request, approximation-algorithms, randomized-algorithms

I've been thinking about algorithms of the form where a quantity $c$ can be viewed as the expectation of some estimator (random variable) $X$ and the expectation is taken over some multivariate Gaussian, a formal way to maybe write this is
$$c = E_{\mathcal{N}(\mu, \Sigma)}[X]$$

The only one that I know of is this one [here](https://arxiv.org/abs/1609.02416) to estimate the permanent of a Hermitian positive semi-definite matrix. There they have access to $N$ samples and don't seem to factor the cost of obtaining the samples into the computation.

I'm curious if there are other "well-known" examples of randomized algorithms where the randomness comes from a Gaussian distribution? I'm curious about how other algorithms factor the cost of obtaining samples into their time complexity. This question is somewhat addressed in this older [question](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/8169/computational-complexity-of-random-sampling/8171#8171).

Comment: The most famous Johnson-Lindenstrauss construction is probably the one using a matrix of i.i.d. Gaussians.

Comment: There's some Markov chain algorithms, such as the Langevin algorithm or Hamiltonian Monte Carlo, in which the random steps are chosen based on a Gaussian.

Comment: [The Gaussian mechanism in differential privacy.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Additive_noise_mechanisms#Gaussian_Mechanism)

Comment: The Goemans-Williamson 0.878-approximation algorithm for Max-cut uses a random hyperplane, defined by its normal, a Gaussian vector.